# Saving FFT Spectrum in Fmod Studio C++

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, fmod, spectrum

I'm trying to save the Spectrum in my FMOD_DSP_PARAMETER_FFT but I'm only receiving the spectrum full of zeros, if you can watch my mistake I will agree, I think that I'm not connecting well the DSP to the channel or something similar because I don't find the error in the code.

My code now is like this:

```
FMOD::System     *system;
FMOD::Sound      *sound1;
FMOD::Channel    *channel = 0;
FMOD::ChannelGroup *mastergroup;
FMOD::ChannelControl *control;
FMOD::DSP         *mydsp, *dsphead, *dspchannelmixer;
FMOD::DSPConnection *conection;
FMOD_RESULT       result;
unsigned int      version;
result = FMOD::System_Create(&system);
result = system->getVersion(&version);

result = system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, NULL);
result = system->createSound("MySong.mp3",FMOD_DEFAULT, 0, &sound1);
result = sound1->setMode(FMOD_LOOP_NORMAL);
result = system->playSound(sound1, 0, true, &channel);

/*
Create the DSP effect.
*/
result = system->getMasterChannelGroup(&mastergroup);
result = system->createDSPByType(FMOD_DSP_TYPE_FFT, &mydsp);

result = system->getMasterChannelGroup(&mastergroup);
result = mastergroup->addDSP(0, mydsp);


result = mydsp->setBypass(true);
result = mydsp->setActive(true);

char s[256];
unsigned int len;
float freq[32];

float fft = 0;
std::vector<float> fftheights;
float m_spectrum_data[FFT_NUM_BINS];

while (1) { //program loop

unsigned int ms = 0;
unsigned int lenms = 0;
bool         playing = 0;
bool         paused = 0;
int          channelsplaying = 0;
  if (channel)
  {
    FMOD::Sound *currentsound = 0;
    result = channel->setPaused(false);
    result = channel->setMute(false);
    result = channel->isPlaying(&playing);
    result = channel->getPaused(&paused);
    result = channel->setVolume(0.5);
    result = channel->getPosition(&ms, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_MS);
    channel->getCurrentSound(&currentsound);
    if (currentsound)
    {
      result = currentsound->getLength(&lenms, FMOD_TIMEUNIT_MS);


    }
  }

  system->getChannelsPlaying(&channelsplaying);


  FMOD_DSP_PARAMETER_FFT *fftparameter;
  float val;
  char s[256];
  unsigned int len;
  float *data = 0;
  float freq[32];
  int rate, chan, nyquist;
  int windowsize = 1024;

  result = system->getSoftwareFormat(&rate, 0, 0);


  result = mydsp->setParameterInt(FMOD_DSP_FFT_WINDOWTYPE, FMOD_DSP_FFT_WINDOW_TRIANGLE);

  result = mydsp->setParameterInt(FMOD_DSP_FFT_WINDOWSIZE, windowsize);

  result = mydsp->getParameterFloat(FMOD_DSP_FFT_DOMINANT_FREQ, &val, 0, 0);

  result = mydsp->getParameterData(FMOD_DSP_FFT_SPECTRUMDATA, (void **)&fftparameter, &len, s, 256);

  nyquist = windowsize / 2;

  for (chan = 0; chan < 2; chan++)
  {
    float average = 0.0f;
    float power = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < nyquist - 1; ++i)
    {
      float hz = i * (rate * 0.5f) / (nyquist - 1);
      int index = i + (16384 * chan);

      if (fftparameter->spectrum[chan][i] > 0.0001f) // arbitrary cutoff to filter out noise
      {
        average += data[index] * hz;
        power += data[index];
      }
    }

    if (power > 0.001f)
    {
      freq[chan] = average / power;
    }
    else
    {
      freq[chan] = 0;
    }
  }
  printf("\ndom freq = %d : %.02f %.02f\n", (int)val, freq[0], freq[1]);
}
```

My fftparameter->spectrum is always an array of zero values...
Is posible to connect it without modify the sound that is playing??
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried moving the playSound call to be after you set up the DSP channels?

Comment: Still with the same result...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few standout issues in your code example.

1. The FFT DSP has been bypassed with `result = mydsp->setBypass(true);` causing it to not process.
2. There are no calls to System::update in the main loop.
3. The main loop has no sleep so it will spin as fast as possible.

I think your main issue is probably the setBypass call, use setBypass(false).